# In azure sql db how to enforce the rule users should only connect using applicationintent=Readonly

Tags: azure-sql-database, read-only-routing

For sql server availability groups we enforce the rule “users should only read from DR nodes” by first creating logins and users in the primary node and then dropping /disabling the logins on the primary . Is there a way to do the same for azure sql db?  We can tell the users to connect only using applicationIntent=ReadOnly but how do we enforce at least monitor that from sql server side . Any input is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always monitor [connections](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-connections-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and [sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-sessions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) on the primary.  And see in [Query Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/monitoring-performance-by-using-the-query-store?view=sql-server-ver16) if ad-hoc reporting queries are running on the primary.

And if you see sessions or queries there that should be using a secondary, go have a chat with the user.

Comment: Thank you David!